# Arc Hydro Batch Subwatershed Delineation does not contain catchment boundaries/falls short?

Tags: arc-hydro

[image]

When running the Batch Subwatershed Delineation in Arc Hydro for 10.2/10.2.1, many of the output subwatershed areas do not completely enclose the catchments/adjointcatchments they are are representing.  Instead the subwatershed polygon tends to begin about 1/2 raster cell size above the drainagepoint (which followed all necessary batch procedures before application) and in many cases it appears to run out of area from the nearby catchment boundaries and do not cross over the str grid or drainage point.

Why might this be happening and how do I resolve it to encompass the entire catchment/adjoint catchment areas?

Comment: Welcome to our site! Could you provide some details or examples? Often mis-registration phenomena like you describe stem from inconsistencies between the desired output and system settings controlling the origin, cellsize, and extent of output rasters, so providing that information can be helpful. A clearer explanation or illustration of what you mean by "run out of area" will also help readers understand your situation.

Comment: Thanks. The problem seems to occur when narrow boundaries of the catchment polygons around a DrainagePoint don't allow for the subwatershed polygon to extend beyond its suspected expanse that I would assume to be the catchment and neighboring adjointcatchment areas which contain the extended Str grid (or drainageline). Subwatersheds with areas above the drainagepoint extend throughout most or all of the catchment and adjointcatchment area as originally expected. The cell sizes are 10'x10' and the applied DEM was a signed integer (not floating, though I couldn't figure out the conversion).

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.